# How do I select a column from a JavaScript sourced DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f1jLf5en/) as an example, how would I select a column from this table? The code below doesn't trigger and I'm not getting anything from the [column()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column()) function page or the column-selector page.

```
alert(typeof table.column());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://datatables.net/reference/api/) page specifies that the API can be accessed through the object returned by the `DataTable` constructor, or through the object returned by the `api` function of the `dataTable` object.

> The API can be accessed through the following methods:
>
> ```
> $( selector ).DataTable();
> $( selector ).dataTable().api();
> new $.fn.dataTable.Api( selector );
> ```

Your `table` variable is set as the return value of the `dataTable` constructor, so you need to use `table.api().column()` rather than `table.column()`. Alternatively, set `table` using the `DataTable` constructor.

Comment: Fantastique! Thank you very much.